# Rust: Segfault when executing specific line of code from a dynamically loaded library

Tags: segmentation-fault, rust, dlopen, dynamic-library

Im writing a simple plugin-based system in Rust to gain some skills and experience using the language. My system dynamically loads libraries and executes them at runtime to initialize each plugin. Im running into an interesting segfault issue when executing code from a dynamically-loaded library.

This is the code to load and run the plugin init function: (this bit works fine)

```
pub fn register_plugins<'rp>(&'rp mut self)
{
    let p1 = match DynamicLibrary::open(Some("librust_plugin_1.so")) {
            Ok(lib) => lib,
            Err(error) => fail!("Could not load the library: {}", error)
    };
    let s1: extern "Rust" fn(&PluginSystem) = unsafe {
        match p1.symbol("init") {
            Err(error) => fail!("Could not load function init: {}", error),
            Ok(init) => mem::transmute::<*mut u8, _>(init)
        }
    };
    s1(&self.ps);
}
```

This is the init function within the plugin library:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub fn init(ps:&mut PluginSystem)
{
    ps.register_plugin("ps1"); //<-- Segfault is in this method
    ps.add_new_hook_with_closure("onLoad", "ps1", "display greeting.", 10, test1);
    println!("Initialized plugin.");
}
```

As commented, the segfault occurs within the register_plugin function of the PluginSystem struct named ps. This struct is borrowed from the calling method (in the first code chunk).

This is the register_plugin function in PluginSystem:

```
pub fn register_plugin(&mut self, plugin_name: &'s str)
{
    if ! self.plugins.contains_key(&plugin_name) {
        let hm = HashMap::new(); //<-- Segfault Here
        self.plugins.insert(plugin_name, hm);
    };
}
```

The segfault occurs when executing `HashMap::new()` in this code block;

I have tried implementing this function differently, as in:

```
pub fn register_plugin(&mut self, plugin_name: &'s str)
{
    match self.plugins.entry(plugin_name) {
                Vacant(entry) => {
                        entry.set(HashMap::new()); //<-- Segfault Here
                    }
                Occupied(mut entry) => {  }
            }
}
```

But I get exactly the same issue.

If I skip the register_plugin function, and run other code in the dynamically-loaded library, it works fine. In fact the only code which this segfaults on is `HashMap::new()`.

Is this a bug or an existing issue, or am I doing something wrong?

More Info:
I compiled rust with debugging symbols in order to step through HashMap code to find the issue. It looks like it doesn't even try to execute the new() function, when debugging the code, when stepping into `HashMap::new()` the debugger steps directly to this function in unwind.rs:

```
pub unsafe fn try(f: ||) -> ::core::result::Result<(), Box<Any + Send>> {
    let closure: Closure = mem::transmute(f);
    let ep = rust_try(try_fn, closure.code as *mut c_void,
                  closure.env as *mut c_void);
    return if ep.is_null() {
        Ok(())
    } else {
        let my_ep = ep as *mut Exception; //<-- Steps into this line
        rtdebug!("caught {}", (*my_ep).uwe.exception_class);
        let cause = (*my_ep).cause.take(); //<-- Segfaults Here
        uw::_Unwind_DeleteException(ep);
        Err(cause.unwrap())
    };
```

The Segfault occurs in the `cause.take()` function, I think it is because my_ep.cause is null or inaccessible. So something is generating an invalid exception, and `try` function is choking on it and giving the segfault. This is related to calling the HashMap code from the dynamically-loaded library, but I don't know how it is related.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:
My platform is linux x64, im using a freshly built rust from git master as of yesterday (28 Oct '14).

Comment: What platform are you using? The unwinder (which `rust_try` ultimately depends on) is highly specific to the certain platform and each unwinder implementation has its own quirks.

Comment: Woops, forgot to add that in the question. Im using linux x64, with freshly built rust from git master as of yesterday.

Comment: @AshleySommer: The type of `s1` is wrong: it says `fn(&PluginSystem)` but the actual function takes the `PluginSystem` by mutable reference. You'll need to change the call to `s1(&mut self.ps)`, too.

Comment: @FrancisGagné Thank you. I made those changes you suggested, though I am still experiencing the same segfault issue relating to HashMap::new().

Comment: For those following along, see the reddit thread [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2kjpiv/segfault_when_executing_specific_line_of_code/) for more discussion about this issue.

I can make the problem go away by changing this instance of `HashMap `to a `TreeMap`, but then I get a another segfault elsewhere in the program (not in a plugin) when calling `contains_key` on a different HashMap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened an issue on GitHub about this ([here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18521)), with a minimal test case, and it was solved in a few hours.

Basically, it was because rustc default to statically linking libstd when building executables, and dynamically linking when building libraries.
So main was using a static libstd, and when loading plugin.so at runtime, the plugin uses a dynamic libstd. Weird memory issues happen after that.

Fixed by adding `-C prefer-dynamic` to rustc for the main executable.